# getting null form value in controller action method passing through ajax post request in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
function register() {
    var jsObj = {};
    var data = $('#register').serializeArray();
    $.each(data,function(index,feild){
        jsObj[feild.name] = feild.value;
        console.log(feild.name+" -- "+feild.value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Signup/Registeration',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsObj),//this is my data in json format
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

}
```

this my controller action method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Registeration(SignUp data)
    {
        return Json(data);
    }
```

this is my signup class

```
public class SignUp
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string cpassword { get; set; }
}
```

[image: This my server response]
[image: This is my form data passing in json format]

Comment: You have extra space on "cpassword " and "password " on request. Remove those spaces from input names.

Answer (score 0):

In your very bottom image, the Request parameters for password and cpassword have an extra whitespace after them.  I.e They are currently "password " and "cpassword " instead of "password" and "cpassword" respectively.

[image]